# Nav Overflows box-shadow

Tags: html, css, nav, box-shadow

The nav tag is overflowing the box shadow in the css , hence its displaying border. I have tried everything from adding visibility: none on to using the z-index property on the nav tag, but none of them work. The website is http://www.lvowebdesign.nl. I know the CSS is not clean and there are lots of mistakes, but I need someone with fresh eyes before it drives me insane. There are lot of '!important's because the bulma css would override the css. What is happening with the nav tag? Can this be fixed?

Here is the HTML code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.0.6"></script>
<!-- <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit&onload=onScriptLoad" async defer></script> -->
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?" async defer></script>
<script defer src="/fontawesome-pro-5.0.2/svg-with-js/js/fontawesome-all.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css">

<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
  <div>
    <div class="emptyheader">
      <div class="leeuw">
        <embed class="logo"src="logo.svg"/ height="180px">
      </div>
    </div>

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="http://www.lvowebdesign.nl/index.php#">
            <img class='imgmessage' src ='graphics/homepage.svg' height='50' width = '50'/>
            Homepage
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://www.lvowebdesign.nl/ref.php">
            <img class='imgmessage' src ='graphics/testemonials.svg' height='50' width= '50'/>
            Testimonals
          </a>
        </li>

        <li class="noline">
          <a  class="modalbox" href="contact-master.php" >
            <img class='imgmessage' src ='graphics/email.svg' height='50' width = '50'/>
            Contact 
          </a>
        </li>       
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Here is the css code:

```css
nav {
  padding: 0px 0 0px !important;
  height: 60px !important;
  background: white !important;
}

nav ul {
  text-align: center !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  padding: 0 !important;

  list-style-position: inside !important;
}

nav li {
  list-style: none !important;
  display: inline !important;
  padding: 0 7px !important;
  border-right: solid 1px orangered !important;
}

nav a {
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-size: 18px !important;

  color: orangered;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  ;
}

nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline !important;
  color: darkblue;

}

nav li.noline {
  border-right: none !important;
  color: darkblue;

}

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,

section {
  display: block;
  z-index: 4 !important;

  box-shadow:
      inset 10px 0px 10px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
      inset -10px 0px 10px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
  {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none
}

button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  margin: 0
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

*,
::after,
::before {
  box-sizing: inherit
}

a {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  font-size: 100% !important;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: transparent;
}

/* change colours to suit your needs */
ins {
  background-color: #ff9;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* change colours to suit your needs */
mark {
  background-color: #ff9;
  color: #000;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
}

del {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

abbr[title],
dfn[title] {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
  cursor: help;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/* change border colour to suit your needs */
hr {
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input,
select {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/************** BEGIN STYLES ****************/

/* BACKGROUND COLOR */



article,
nav,
aside,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
section {
  display: block;
}


body {
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif !important;

  background: orangered !important;
  background-repeat: repeat-x !important;
  color: #4a4a4a;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;

  height: 100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/**************** HEADERS  **************/

h2 {
  font-size: 110% !important;
  padding: 0px 5px !important;
  clear: both;
  color: orangered !important;
}

h2 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: default;
}

h2 a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

h3 {
  padding: 9px 0px 0px 8px;
}

img.portfollo {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px;

}

img.floatleft {
  float: left;
}

p {
  text-align: justify !important;
  padding: 9px 5px 0px 8px !important;
}

/**************** LAYOUTS ***************/

/* general margin and padding */


section {
  padding: 35px 75px !important;
}

section {
  padding: 35px 0important;
}

header {
  padding: 2px 5pximportant;
}

footer p {
  margin: 0 75pximportant;
}

footer div p {
  text-align: centerimportant;
}


/* layout continued */


section,
footer,
div.push,
.wrapper {
  background: #fff;
}

.wrapper,
footer {
  width: 100% !important;
  min-width: 768px !important;
  max-width: 1000px !important;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  margin: 0 auto -155px !important;

}

img.imgmessage {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#message {
  font-size: 15px !important;
  background-color: white !important;
}


#container {
  display: table !important;
}

#leftcol,
#rightcol,
#content,
#inleftcol,
#inrightcol {
  display: table-cell;
}

#rightcol {
  min-width: 300px !important;
  width: 35%;
  padding: 0 3%;
  border-left: solid 1px #CCC;
}

#content {
  width: 65%;
  padding: 0 3%;
}

#row1,
#row2,
#row3 {}

#rightcol p {}

.innertable {
  display: table;
}

.inrow {
  display: table-row;
}

.inleftcol,
.inrightcol {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-right: 35px !important;

  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.inrightcol {
  padding: 0 0 0 3%;
}


section {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: justify;
  width: 100%;
}




.push {
  height: 155px;
  /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
  margin: 0 auto;
}

footer {
  border-top: solid 1px #CCC;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 15px;

}

footer div {
  margin: 45px auto;
  text-align: center;
}


/* HEADER */

header {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
  height: 205px;
}

h1 {
  display: block-inline !important;
  width: 900px;
  text-align;
  center !important;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px !important;
  /* border: 1px solid green; */
  color: #FF6F00;
}

.emptyheader {
  display: block-inline;
  text-align: center;
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
}

.leeuw {
  display: table-cell;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `box-shadow` propriety to the nav as well, but it is just a quick fix. I really suggest you to organize you code better and you can add the `box-shadow` to a main div.

```
nav {
  padding: 0px 0 0px !important;
  height: 60px !important;
  background: white !important;
  box-shadow:
      inset 10px 0px 10px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
      inset -10px 0px 10px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```